# Can I modify anchor tag href in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Not sure if this is possible but wanted to know if htaccess has a trick...

Say I have anchor tag href like this -

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php?id=12345">Click here</a>
```

I have changed the URL structure using mod_rewrite but wanted to know if i can hide the actual URL in href using htaccess.

i.e when a user hover over the anchor tag, the browser displays http://example.com/index.php?id=12345 at the bottom. All I want the browser to display is http://example.com/index/12345 without changing it manually on all my pages.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Nope, I don't think `htaccess` can do that much. If you don't want to do it manually, you can use a small JS function on all pages.

Comment: I don't think so either, if /index.php?id=12345 is actually in the HTML. If your HTML generated by a php script? This you could just make a small change there. Or if hand coded, a text editor such as edit plus may be able to do a global search and replace using a macro?

Comment: No, but this can pretty easily be solved with a simple command-line `sed`

Comment: I'm looking for a smarter solution because I have lot of pages to edit if I opt to change it manually. May be the only option left is to search and mass edit using notepad++.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the link to the following?

```
<a href="http://example.com/index/12345">Click here</a>
```

As you can change the .htaccess I expect that you own or adminstrate this domain. So it should be possible.

If the links are generated by PHP code, then I suggest you to implement and use a translation function like:

```
function beautify($ugly) {
    // your logic comes here
    return $nice; // ;)
}
```

... and wrap it around the existing code that currently outputs the urls. This would have two advantages:

- It's easy and more failsafe to migrate to the new url scheme
- From now on you have control over all url related code using a single function

Answer (score 0):

I agree, htaccess can't help you. I guess you'll have to change them manually.
I wish I could be of more help

Answer (score 0):

No.  htaccess is for processing input to the web server, not data sent back from the server.

If you use jQuery you could have it rewrite the href when the page loads using something like this.

```
$(function(){
    $("a").each(function() { 
      this.href = 'some_new_url that you made based on the one in this.href';
    });
});
```